# How to add condition on where clause based on optional parameter using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an 'optional' parameter in my stored procedure, if my parameter has certain value then I need to add a conditional where statement in my existing query.

I don't want to have a separate statement and basically here what I want to do it but I'm not sure if possible with SQL Server

```
@myRole varchar=''  -- here's optional parameter

SELECT blah blah 
FROM myTable
WHERE 
     <I_have_here_existing_conditions>
     AND
         here I want to add another condition based on my @myRole parameter-something like
      if myRole='Employee' then add to where condition: myStatus = 'Y'*
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Can `@myRole` be `NULL`, or will it always be an empty string if not used?

Comment: [This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) is a good read for the task.

Comment: I know you don't want an extra statement, but it may be much more performant. Perhaps dynamic SQL if you want to avoid repetition

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select * 
from yourtable
where
 [other conditions]
and (@myRole <> 'Employee' OR  myStatus = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression like this:

```
where <other conditions>
     and case when @myRole = 'Employee' then myStatus else 'Y' end = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming @myrole is either `null` or a defined value,

```
select *
from Table
where ...
and (@myrole is null or (myStatus='Y' and @myrole='Employee'))
```

if it's always defined as `''` then just use  `and (@myrole='' or`